Deviation suffered by light ray incident on a surface
Problem:

Figure shows two spherical surfaces of radii $R$ and $2R$ separating three transparent media of refractive indices $\mu_1=1, \mu_2=2$ and $\mu_3=4$. A ray of light travelling in medium $\mu_1=1$ is incident on the outer sphere tangentially. Find the net deviation suffered by the light ray in the clockwise direction.


My thinking:
The light ray hits the outer surface tangentially and bends towards the inner surface. After this, would it

Enter the second surface or
Touch the second surface tangentially or
Not enter the second surface?

The answer would be different in each of the 3 cases. Which one should I proceed with?
Question: What would be the net deviation suffered by the light ray in the above problem?

Also, how do I know if TIR would occur or if the light ray would just refract out the other side?

To find the net deviation use Snell's Law
$$ \mu_1 sin(\theta_1) = \mu_2 sin(\theta_2) $$
At first interface, $$ 1 \times sin(90°) = 2 \times sin(\theta_2) \implies sin(\theta_2) = 1/2 \implies \theta_2 = 30°$$
Using Trigonometry, we can show that the light touches the second surface tangentially as $$ \theta_2 = sin^{-1}\left(\frac{R}{2R}\right) = 30° $$



Following from Anchal Kumar Sharma's solution, we conclude
$$\angle OED=\angle ODE=30° \implies \angle EOD=120°.$$
In triangle $BOE$, using trigonometry, $\angle OBE =30°$ and we also get
$$\angle AOD = \angle BOE =60°.$$
Now,
$$\angle EOD +\angle AOD +\angle BOE +\angle AOB =360° \implies \angle AOB =120°.$$
In quadrilateral $ACBO$,
$$\angle AOB +\angle BCA +\angle CAB +\angle OBC =360° \implies \angle BCA =60°.$$
The angle of deviation is $180°-\angle BCA =120°$ (anticlockwise) which is same as $240°$ clockwise.
